# p-selectButton does not work Angular/PrimeNg

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm trying to use  on my Angular project, in the HTML file I have this :

```
<div class="content-section introduction">
  <div>
    <span class="feature-title">Free Memory Space Monitoring</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
<p-selectButton [options]="cities2" optionLabel="name"></p-selectButton>
<p>here</p>
</div>
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

I'm using Angular 9.0.1 and PrimeNG 9.0.0, I have installed and setup everything, I also added `import {SelectButtonModule} from 'primeng/selectbutton';` on my app.modules.ts, I also added `SelectButtonModule`in the imports, the charts are working well, but this SelectButton doesnt work or even display.
I'm a newbies thanks for your help :)

Comment: can you share code snippet on stackblitz?

Comment: Same thing happening here ["primeng": "^10.0.0-rc.3"] , showed me the following error. "..Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class"